# Why are several versions in production a key to choose GitFlow over GitHub flow?

Tags: git, gitflow, sdlc

I've seen in many places, [one of them here](https://www.freshconsulting.com/insights/blog/git-development-workflows-git-flow-vs-github-flow/) (and also in the guiding questions of GitVersion) that, when coming to determine whether or not to use GitFlow, one key consideration is whether or not I need to maintain several versions in production.

So if the answer is yes - GitFlow can fit you. What objective advantage does GitFlow have over GitHub flow regarding this scenario?

The reason I’m asking: Other than the fact the GitFlow strictly defines the naming convention of branches so we have "hotfix" branches, from a technical POV I don't see why GitHub flow doesn't allow you to assign a team of developers to branch off of the buggy version (identified by tag) while the rest are still working on the next features that will be merged to main?

Comment: if you did that then you have changed to gitflow

Comment: https://www.endoflineblog.com/follow-up-to-gitflow-considered-harmful See the “I can’t delete my release branches” section

Comment: @jpmc26 That article is kind of funny. The author originally started with "I don't like Git Flow" (and IMHO for uninformed reasons), so he offered an alternative. Then he started responding to some of the criticisms, so he offered workarounds and tweaks to his strategy, which if you do all of them, makes it nearly identical to Git Flow again.

Comment: @TTT If you had paid *any* attention to the article, you'd have noticed that it's not at all like Gitflow. And the core difference is obvious: OneFlow eschews the systematic permanent branches and non-fast-forward merges that Gitflow requires and that make your repository history look like a game of Guitar Hero, by limiting them to only the cases where they're absolutely necessary. If you don't have all the parallel branches being merged into each other constantly, you're not using Gitflow. OneFlow's goal is to use Git's features properly to generate a simpler history, and it does so.

Comment: @jpmc26 Trust me, I paid attention. 1.) Git Flow problem: you don't need two long lived branches. One Flow Solution: just have one branch. Complaint: But then I have to find the latest tag to know what's in production? Solution: create another long lived branch called `current`, or name it `master` if you prefer. (That just went full circle back to Git Flow.) That is the *exact* reason `master` exists in Git Flow, if you choose to use it.

Comment: @jpmc26 2.) Git Flow problem: I hate merge commits! (Maybe bc advocates of One Flow don't know about --first-parent or aren't comfortable reading a DAG, and that's fine.) One Flow solution: don't use --no-ff. Complaint: But then I lose all the benefits of the merge commit! Solution: you can use --no-ff if you want. Then he presents semi-linear merge as if it isn't compatible with Git Flow, but is compatible with One Flow.

Comment: @TTT Apparently not, because the problem statement was mistakes and confusion. Also, apparently not because in Gitflow, the release branch is a separate branch that is only merged into using non-fast-forward merges that create *distinct commits*, whereas in OneFlow, if you even have a `current` branch, it just gets moved to *an existing commit* when a new tag is created using a fast-forward merge. You don't know what you're talking about. I'm not gonna waste any more time arguing with someone who doesn't have their facts straight.

Comment: @jpmc26 I agree with your comment, except for the part that I don't know what I'm talking about ;-). Of course I know GitFlow has an extra merge on `master` compared to OneFlow. (In fact in OneFlow you could just `git branch -f current` every time you tag a release and skip the "merge" altogether.) Of all the merge commits recommended in Git Flow, merging `release` or `hotfix` into `master` is argubably the one place where --no-ff is redundant, **if** you tag the tip of `release` or `hotfix` before each merge. Everywhere else there *could* be information loss. (Though many people don't care.)

Comment: @jpmc26 I also agree that for many teams the added complexity might not be worth it just to achieve that small information gain provided by extra merge commits. I personally *hate* merge commits on feature branches (so I promote rebase there), but *love* merge commits when PRs/MRs bring *more than one* commit into a protected branch. I'm less passionate about merge commits on `master`, though when I use Git Flow I do enjoy using first-parent view to compare release contents, and then not all merges into `master` have to be tagged, if you don't wish to.

Answer (score 4):

GitHub Flow doesn't support multiple versions being supported at once. A release occurs after every commit to the main branch. GitHub Flow is designed for use in environments that are practicing Continuous Delivery or Continuous Deployment, where the commit to the main branch triggers the deployment. If you are not deploying shortly after a commit to the main branch, then GitHub Flow isn't a good fit.

On the other hand, in Git Flow, deployments happen from release branches made off of the main branch. You can then keep the release branch around for patches for as long as the version exists in production, applying the patches to all of the supported versions, using either cherry-picking or manually depending on the state of the code for each version.

In GitHub Flow, there's no reason why a team of developers can't branch off the buggy version identified by a tag. However, since GitHub Flow is designed to support only one version in production, the buggy version would always be the current head of the main branch. The developers fixing the bug and the developers working on a new feature would both be branched off of the head of the main branch and, depending on who finished first, the other group would likely want to synchronize their branch with the updates committed to main.

---

It's also important to note that there are at least two versions of the GitHub Flow. In [the original version](https://githubflow.github.io/), changes are merged to the main branch and the main branch is deployed shortly after each merge (which may result in two merges close together being deployed together). In [the newer version](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/), the feature branch is deployed and then merged into the main branch.

My personal preference is the first version, where the main branch is deployed to production. However, there is [another question here on Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/343604/4) as well as [a GitHub blog post](https://github.blog/2012-08-29-deploying-at-github/) that go into details about how the newer version works for GitHub. It seems like they have infrastructure in place to ensure the safety of deployment from feature branches to production and prevent a feature branch that is missing commits from being deployed.

Thanks to [TTT](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/153056/ttt) for finding some of this information and pointing it out in the comments.

Comment: I think you're looking at it backwards. What do you mean by "GitHub flow doesn't support.." ? You mean it doesn't fit a situation you have several versions being supported at once? That again sounds like "just because". My question is: why isn't GitHub flow ALSO suitable for a situation in which you have several versions in production? And since from a technical POV there is no reason you can't branch off of a  buggy tag and fix the bug -as you stated yourself - the question arises - so why isn't GitHub flow suitable for such usecases?

Comment: @YoavKlein I'm not looking at it backwards. The creators of GitHub Flow did not need to support multiple versions in production, so they didn't create a model that supports this. GitHub Flow is well-defined and deployments happen from the main branch, so there's no opportunity to deploy other branches to other environments. The moment you deploy a branch that isn't the main branch to the production environment, you are no longer using GitHub Flow.

Comment: I really don't understand why I SHOULD care about how GitHub flow came to be. Honestly - I don't. As far as I concern, GitHub flow and GitFlow are 2 strategies widely used, so there is a lot of reading material and best practices around it (Again - don't care about how they came to be). Now, GitFlow is said to be more suited to a specific usecase, and my question is - WHAT exactly in GitFlow specification HAS that GitHub flow DOESN'T that make it more suitable. If you can answer my question - please do. If not - let others.

Comment: @YoavKlein If you read my answer, I did address that. Git Flow has release branches that can be deployed to one or more environments and there's no mapping between release branches and environments (they don't even need to be production environments). GitHub Flow does not have release branches - the only branch that can be released and deployed is the main branch and there's a 1:1 mapping between the main branch and the production environment. Understanding why the strategy was developed and what problems it was developed to solve is key to understanding when you should use it.

Comment: as far as I know,  release branches are branched off of develop, and are short lived branches that are deleted once merged to master

Comment: @YoavKlein That is not mandatory. If you are only supporting one release in production, then that could be true and nothing in the definition of Git Flow prevents it. However, if you are supporting multiple releases, the release branch would not be deleted until the release is no longer supported. It depends entirely on your release strategy.

Comment: Re: this statement, "If you are not deploying shortly after a commit to the main branch, then GitHub Flow isn't a good fit."... I would have thought the same thing, but recently I re-read the GitHub Flow suggested deployment model, and it (strangely?) suggests deploying your feature branch to prod **before** merging to main. Then, if you like it, merge to main, and if you don't like it, re-deploy main. I feel like that would work if you rebase your feature branch onto main before deploy (or merge main into it), but without either of those, it seems dangerous since it may be behind main.

Comment: @TTT That seems to be the difference between [the original GitHub flow](https://githubflow.github.io/) and [the most recent GitHub flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/). I don't like the idea of pushing a random branch to production since it could be out-of-sync with stuff in the main branch. Merging and deploying shortly after merge feels safer, and was the original flow. I'd be curious what drove the change and why it was done.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I completely agree. I recently wrote a branching strategy document for a new repo and said we're using GitHub Flow, and then a co-worker asked me about deploying to Prod from a feature branch and I said "Huh?" Then she pointed to the more recent link and I died a little inside and said, "OK then, I guess we're *not* using GitHub Flow. Let me figure out a better name for what we *are* doing." ;-)

Comment: Regarding the new GitHub flow design, I found a question with [GitHub's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/343604/153056).